# When adding a custom activity to a workflow, I get a "The requested record not found" error

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have a custom workflow activity that does get registered. However, when I go to add it to a workflow, I get a "The requested record was not found or you do not have permission sufficient permission to view it" error.  I'm an admin and it was registered using the same user account. There is no information in the trace file.  What could be causing this?

UPDATE: Please note that this is occurring not at runtime, but at design time. I.e. I can't actually add this activity to a workflow. When I try I get the above error.

UPDATE 2: I simplified my code to this and still get the same message:

```
using System;
using System.Workflow.ComponentModel;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Crm.Workflow;
using MicroFour.StrataFrame.Data;

namespace Fox.Crm.CustomWorkflowActivities
{
  [CrmWorkflowActivity( "Get Entity Link", "Fox Tools" )]
  public class GetEntityLinkActivity
    : Activity
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty FullNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "FullName"
                                                                                           , typeof( string )
                                                                                           , typeof( GetEntityLinkActivity ) );

    [CrmInput( "FullName" )]
    public string FullName
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue( FullNameProperty ); }
      set { SetValue( FullNameProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "Message"
                                                                                           , typeof( string )
                                                                                           , typeof( GetEntityLinkActivity ) );

    [CrmOutput( "Message" )]
    public string Message
    {
      get { return (string)GetValue( MessageProperty ); }
      set { SetValue( MessageProperty, value ); }
    }

    protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute( ActivityExecutionContext executionContext )
    {
      this.Message = string.Format( "Hellow {0}", this.FullName );

      //-- Return that we successfully determined URL and link.
      return ActivityExecutionStatus.Closed;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks pretty innocent ;)

How is your assembly registered (database, GAC, disk)?  Is the MicroFour.* assembly the one you import?  If not, does it exist in the Program Files/Microsoft Dynamics CRM/Server/bin/assembly directory?

Does the workflow editor blow when you open it or when you select your custom activity?

Comment: The workflow editor blows when I select the activity (it never gets added to the actual workflow to allow it to be opened). 

The MircoFour assemblies are in the bin folder. Is there supposed to be an assembly sub folder? There isn't one there now, so I guess if that is where it needs to be, I'll have to add it.

I'm using a registration tool that uses the CrmService.Create (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa613632.aspx) method. I'm not seeing how that allows for the location to be set. As should be obvious, I'm still learning about all this meta data/registration stuff. :-/

Comment: If I recall correctly you'll need to put your assemblies in both
Microsoft DYnamics CRM/CRMWeb/bin and Microsoft Dynamics CRM/Server/bin/assembly.  The first is the CRM Website and I believe is needed for the UI to read your activity metadata.  The second is for the server role (async service in particular here) to be able to load your assembly.